# A word/phrase for something that often comes up in conversations

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, idiom-requests

> To find a affordable apartment was a big problem. University students would often
> struggle to find a place to live. As I recall, that
> was a —————— (= popular topic of our conversations = we always talked about it).

I want a word/phrase/idiom that means ‘a common topic of conversation’ or ‘something that often comes up in conversations’.

I have here ‘hot topic’ and ‘talking point’ but they do not fit into the above context, as they mean topics such as political ones that involve arguing and taking side.

Comment: Do you want something neutral? There are a lot of negative terms like platitude, commonplace, cliche, truism, familiar tune, same old song, for things that you don't like having endlessly repeated, but you want something that is OK to be repeated?

Comment: How about "recurring topic" ?

Comment: I actually think "hot topic" is fine; no evidence that it refers to political topics, although it [can be topics that are disputed](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/a-hot-issue-topic-etc) it isn't necessarily one there's an argument over, just one that's discussed.

Comment: @StuartF Yes, neutral. It can be any recurring topic.

Comment: @StuartF But my context doesn’t involve discussion where there are sides to take.

Comment: Is there a word/phrase you’ve heard for this that you can't quite remember? Or are you looking for an original description?

Comment: Ooh, I have a gold badge–forgot about that–which means my vote to reopen takes immediate effect. After looking at the answers in the [older question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/192429/whats-an-idiom-for-something-that-youve-heard-many-times), I believe they are inappropriate in a formal context. For example, *“As I recall, that was* **an old chestnut**”,  works in a conversation but not in a report.

Comment: @Mari-Lou A The correct procedure is surely still to close here as a duplicate question. New answers are legitimate at the original, which does not bar formal expressions ... and OP here disallows 'hot topic' on the grounds of domain rather than register.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I'm happy to close questions as duplicates when I see the answers in the older questions apply. In this case, the old answers are inappropriate as can be seen by these rather unique answers, answers that do not replicate none of the older solutions,  answers which are not duplicates of others as so very often happens. Tell me how the answers "clichéd" and  "Nothing new under the sun“ can apply here? Yes, nothing prevents someone from posting more formal alternatives but they would be happier in this home.

Comment: @Mari-Lou A  '... was old hat' / 'was an old chestnut' / 'sounded like a broken record' obviously fit here. How can 'What's an idiom for something that you've heard many times?' _not_ be a duplicate question? Do we ask a variant using slightly different wording if the answers already provided at a duplicate question aren't sufficient, or do we offer a bonus?

Comment: In an academic context, which this situation appears to suggest, those answers would not fit. This question is related but not a duplicate and this true because of the unique answers posted here. If there's one thing I know about academic writing that is to avoid slang and idioms because not every academician's first language is English. And I would add that alphabet's answer, which is original, would fit better in the older question precisely because it is an idiom.

Comment: @Mari-Lou A I repeat, OP does not mention register as a problem, even though  ‘hot topic’ and ‘talking point’ are discounted on semantic (rather than in one case informal) register grounds. And from ELU.Meta: <<  The Help Center article What does it mean if a question is "closed"? is a network-wide guide about the primary reasons questions should be closed. This generally happens when a question:

is a duplicate of an existing question on the site ...>> It doesn't mention the case where someone wants essentially the same question re-visited and essentially resubmits as being an override.

Comment: @Edwin we disagree. You're not going to change my mind, and I'm not going to change yours.

Comment: The tone and context of the supposed duplicate were quite different, so it's not a matter of adding more answers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Collins Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/recurrent-theme) shows '**recurrent theme**', with some examples.

In your usage, perhaps

> As I recall, that was a recurrent theme in our conversations.

Answer (score 6):

You could say that it was **on everyone's lips.**  [MW defines this as:](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/on%20everyone%27s%2Feverybody%27s%20lips#:%7E:text=%3A%20being%20said%20or%20discussed%20by,trial%20was%20on%20everyone%27s%20lips.)

> being said or discussed by many people

Answer (score 3):

— *ever recurring question, frequent question*

> As I recall, that was an ever recurring question.

Answer (score 2):

As an informal term, at least in BE, "**a regular**" (substantivised adjective) is used:

OED

> **8b. Something done, happening, or appearing regularly in a particular context; a regular or habitual item, feature, event, etc.**
>
> a1980   A. Powell To Keep Ball Rolling III. iv. 77   Among other
> regulars in the critical columns were Elizabeth Bowen's rather staid
> notices of plays.
>
> 2006   N.Y. Times Mag. 26 Mar. 23/1   I have a charcoal grill... I
> cook all the regulars on it: steak, hamburgers, chicken, corn and
> hotdogs.

Answer (score 2):

[***familiar  refrain***](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/familiar-refrain)

...may refer to a topic that often comes up in conversation, sometimes  as a complaint.

...such as "I wish I could find an affordable place to live"

or

"The weather here really sucks."

---

from [Oxford Learner's Dictionary](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/refrain_2)

> **​a comment or complaint that is often repeated**

ex."Complaints about poor food in schools have become a **familiar refrain**."

ex. "The protest began with a small group, but then the others took up the **refrain**."

---

It derives from an old Viennese song, which refers to the a catch phrase that repeats throughout the musical piece.

[Collin's Dictionary](https://dictionary.reverso.net/english-cobuild/old+refrain)

> 1. [Noun] A refrain is a short, simple part of a song, which is repeated many times.
>    ...a refrain from an old song.

> 2. [Noun] A refrain is ***a comment or saying that people often repeat.***

Ex. "Rosa's constant refrain is that she doesn't have a life."

---

In the context of the OP, my re-write:

> "To find an affordable apartment was a big problem. University students would often struggle to find a place to live. As I recall, it was a ***familiar refrain*** over pints in the local dive.

Answer (score 1):

**Common concern** in [LONGMAN](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/concern) (as it name implies) described as ***one that many people share***.

> Monetary Stability as a **Common Concern** in International Law convincingly argues that monetary stability should be recognised as a Common Concern of Humankind.